# SQL delete where NOT IN doesn't work

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-room, android-components

I am using room dao from Android Components.
What i need: insert list, but before - delete all Data from db whose id is different from id from the new list.

here is my simple Data class:

```
class Data{
   String id; //unique for each data class

   //some other data parameters here
}
```

The best option for my task is use `DELETE WHERE NOT IN someArray`. here is example from my code:

```
@Query("DELETE " +
        "FROM MY_TABLE " +
        "WHERE data_id NOT IN ( :listOfId )")
abstract protected fun deleteUniqueData(listOfId:String):Int
```

So when I receive new list that must be saved, I create next String with ids: `"'0','1'"` and call method `deleteUniqueData`.

But each time I called this, I receive `2` as result, which means that there 2 rows was deleted.

Interesting part: when I replace

```
"WHERE data_id NOT IN ( :listOfId )")
```

with

```
"WHERE data_id NOT IN ('0','1')") //same data but hardcoded
```

I receive `0` as result. So it looks like it is some problem with **Room**.

Any ideas why **NOT IN** doesn't work? Or how it can be fixed?

***UPDATE***

here is generated query:

```
"DELETE FROM MY_TABLE WHERE data_id NOT IN ( ? )"
```

Comment: Look at the generated code and see where it is going wrong.

Comment: I was trying! But I came to native methods and can't debug it. Before native methods calls everything looks ok

Comment: "But I come to native methods and can't debug it" -- Room does not use the NDK, so I am not certain what you are referring to. I should have been more clear: look in `build/generated/source/` for the Room-generated code and see what it has there for your `NOT IN` scenario.

Comment: you are right. `nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount` is method of SQLiteConnection.

Comment: @CommonsWare generated query looks ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `deleteUniqueData()` to take a list or array of IDs as the parameter. Do not assemble the comma-delimited list yourself. Room does that.